# How can I set the initial start page in the client-side AGGrid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How can I set the initial start page in the client-side AGGrid (all row data sent in a single response) ?
I have the page index value like 0, 1, 2, etc and I want to use that as the initial page to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

use pagination api to navigate to your desired page.

```
function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
  params.api.paginationGoToPage(4);
}
```

here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FR57gxApZoHS3tgw?open=main.js)